# session expires when adding random controls

Tags: asp.net, session

While developing a web app in asp.net, I tried adding a new control in my page ( a modalPopupExtender). But once added, when loading the page, it redirected me automatically to login page. All I added was:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="testModal" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

While trying to figure out what was causing this problem I tried to add a form in the webpage, which made my session expire (or destroied, not sure exactly) also. Again, all I added was:

```
<form id="testForm" runat="server"></form>
```

What could cause this problem?

Comment: was you debugging when you added the control/form? If you make a change while debugging it can force the app to be recompiled which will ditch your current session.

Comment: yes, i was in debug mode, but I made no changes during that time

Comment: sorry, when I say I debugging, I mean, was you running the app in visual studio? if so, same applies.

Comment: not sure if i understand you.I added the controls and then pressed f5, if that is what you mean

Comment: oh ok. If the app recompiled when you hit F5 it dumped your session. recompile=new session.

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean. Or you don't understand what I mean:). I opened visual studio, added a control pressed F5 and the opened page redirects me to login page. I close visual studio, reopen it, delete that control, press F5 and all works.

Comment: The question is, do you also lose the session if you open the page without doing any changes to the code?

Comment: @Luaan if I don't add those controls everything works just fine, no matter what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the modalPopupExtender you need to add a *TargetControlID* , that is the control that will fire the modal window and also *PopupControlID* which is the control (panel or something) shown when the button is clicked. These two properties are mandatory for the popup to not throw an exception. 
Try to delete all the items that made your app crash, doing a rebuild and add this:

```
<asp:Button ID="someBtn" runat="server"/>

<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="testModal" runat="server" TargetControlID="someBtn" 
                                PopupControlID="Pannel1">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:panel id="Panel1" style="display: none" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div class="PopupBody">
            <p>This is a simple modal dialog</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Controls">
            <input id="btnOkay" type="button" value="Done" />
            <input id="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:panel>
```